# Resample time series data

Tags: python, pandas

I have some random hourly time series data, (lets make some up) how do I resample for a daily max value as well as create a separate df column for the hour of the recorded daily max value?

```
import pandas as pd 
import numpy as np 
from numpy.random import randint
import os

np.random.seed(10)  # added for reproductibility                                                                                                                                                                 

rng = pd.date_range('10/9/2018 00:00', periods=1000, freq='1H') 
df = pd.DataFrame({'Random_Number':randint(1, 100, 1000)}, index=rng)

df.index.name = 'Date'
```

Resample random value:

```
daily_summary = pd.DataFrame()

daily_summary['Random_Number_Resamp'] = df['Random_Number'].resample('D').max()


daily_summary.head()
```

And then an attempt for recording the hour that the daily max value happened...

```
daily_summary['Hour_Map'] = daily_summary.Random_Number_Resamp.index.strftime('%H').astype('int')

daily_summary
```

The code above doesnt throw an attribute error but the `hour_map` will be zero.. How do I accomplish when the `daily_summary` df is created that the hour_map also occurs in this step?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do `groupby`:

```
df.groupby(df.index.normalize())['Random_Number'].agg(['idxmax', 'max'])
```

Output (head):

```
                         idxmax     max
Date        
2018-10-09  2018-10-09 05:00:00     94
2018-10-10  2018-10-10 20:00:00     95
2018-10-11  2018-10-11 15:00:00     97
2018-10-12  2018-10-12 18:00:00     98
2018-10-13  2018-10-13 22:00:00     91
```

Comment: Thanks for the tips... What does the normalize do? Ill also have to study what the aggregate does too

Comment: It truncates all the time to 00:00:00. Aggregation here just applies each function on the group. Of course it can do more.

Comment: is possible to change the `idxmax` max column to just represent the hour as an integer?

Comment: `new_df['hour'] = new_df['idxmax'].dt.hour`?

Comment: For some reason that gives me a key error `KeyError: 'idxmax'`

Comment: See the update, I forgot to add `['Random_Number']` into the original code. Without it, you'll need to do `new_df[('Random_Number','idxmax')]`. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: @ Quang Hoang, could you also help me with this SO question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60509376/resample-time-series-data-multiple-variables

Answer (score 0):

I think I understand what you are looking for...

Just create an hour column in the original df then resample:

```
np.random.seed(10)  # added for reproductibility                                                                                                                                                                 

rng = pd.date_range('10/9/2018 00:00', periods=1000, freq='1H') 
df = pd.DataFrame({'Random_Number':randint(1, 100, 1000)}, index=rng)

df.index.name = 'Date'

# create hour column
df['hour'] = df.index.hour

# resample df
daily_summary = df.resample('D').max()

            Random_Number  hour
Date                           
2018-10-09             94    23
2018-10-10             95    23
2018-10-11             97    23
2018-10-12             98    23
2018-10-13             91    23
```