# Resample time series data multiple variables

Tags: python, pandas, time-series

I have some time series data (making some up) one variable is `value` and the other is `Temperature`

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
np.random.seed(11)

rows,cols = 50000,2
data = np.random.rand(rows,cols) 
tidx = pd.date_range('2019-01-01', periods=rows, freq='T') 
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['Temperature','Value'], index=tidx)
```

***Question***, How do I resample the data per day in a separate pandas df named `daily_summary` with 3 columns each containing:

1. the daily maximum value
2. the hour the maximum value occurred
3. the recorded temperature when the maximum value occurred

I know I can use this code below to find daily maximum value and the hour it occurred:

```
daily_summary = df.groupby(df.index.normalize())['Value'].agg(['idxmax', 'max']) 
daily_summary['hour'] = daily_summary['idxmax'].dt.hour
daily_summary = daily_summary.drop(['idxmax'], axis=1)
daily_summary.rename(columns = {'max':'DailyMaxValue'}, inplace = True)
```

But I am lost trying to incorporate what the temperature was during these daily recordings of the maximum value...

Would using `.loc` be a better method where a loop could just filter thru each day... Something like this???

```
for idx, days in df.groupby(df.index.date):
    print(days)
    daily_summary = df.loc[days['Value'].max().astype('int')]
```

If I run this I can print each day `days` but the `daily_summary` will throw a `TypeError: cannot do index indexing on <class 'pandas.core.indexes.datetimes.DatetimeIndex'> with these indexers [0] of <class 'numpy.int32'>`

Any tips greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can resolve to `idxmax` and `loc`:

```
idx = df.groupby(df.index.normalize())['Value'].idxmax()
ret_df = df.loc[idx].copy()

# get the hour
ret_df['hour'] = ret_df.index.hour

# set date as index
ret_df.index = ret_df.index.normalize()
```

Output:

```
            Temperature     Value  hour
2019-01-01     0.423320  0.998377    19
2019-01-02     0.117154  0.999976    10
2019-01-03     0.712291  0.999497    16
2019-01-04     0.404229  0.999996    21
2019-01-05     0.457618  0.999371    17
```